# Using Django User Model

Tags: python, django, web

I've seen people using the default django user model as a foreign key in two ways:

1)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

2)

```
user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

but when implementing one-to-one relation I've only seen:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1) Are the two ways to define Foreign Keys practically the same?

2) Can you use `user = models.OneToOneField('auth.user')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both works. But, the confusion comes from the fact that `'auth.user'` was used before the add of [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model) in Django 1.5.

Now, in your code I would actually recommend to use neither. instead follow Django [recommendation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#reusable-apps-and-auth-user-model) and use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

or

```
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

This will avoid that your code will stop working in projects where the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting has been changed to a different user model.